# SQL to Combine 2 Column value to Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data like,

```
    ID  SensorID                                Reading_Time                        Value       Type
11  A3C3EB0B-1F5E-3737-B5F7-495BFA238F88    2016-06-02 14:38:16.4980000 -04:00  24.782219   0
12  A3C3EB0B-1F5E-3737-B5F7-495BFA238F88    2016-06-02 14:38:16.4980000 -04:00  23.121845   1
13  A3C3EB0B-1F5E-3737-B5F7-495BFA238F88    2016-06-02 14:38:46.5780000 -04:00  24.77972    0
14  A3C3EB0B-1F5E-3737-B5F7-495BFA238F88    2016-06-02 14:38:46.5780000 -04:00  23.121845   1
```

Type 0 for temp and 1 for Humidity
I have no clue . how to write sql to get result combined like

```
SensorId                             Reading_Time                       Temp      Humidity
A3C3EB0B-1F5E-3737-B5F7-495BFA238F88 2016-06-02 14:38:16.4980000 -04:00 24.782219 23.121845
A3C3EB0B-1F5E-3737-B5F7-495BFA238F88 2016-06-02 14:38:46.5780000 -04:00 24.77972  23.121845
```

I have got 2 solutions from here? Do anyone have any idea about which is faster and best?

Comment: Which database software? SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc.?

Comment: Create an index on reading_time(optional) and join the table to itself where the reading_time matches but the types are not equal.

Comment: microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is using conditional aggregates, which is a good way to make this work with any database.

```
select sensorId,
       reading_time,
       min(case when type = 0 then value end) as Temp,
       min(case when type = 1 then value end) as Humidity
  from tbl
 group by sensorId, reading_time
```

Comment: Correct approach, but you shouldn't include `reading_time` in the aggregation, but instead include it in the `group by` clause.

Comment: @sstan Texhik provided a solution with WITH statement, Do you have any idea about, which is faster? or which is the best approach to go?

Comment: Can't say for sure. I assume that mine should be better because it only reads through the table once.  But test it out, examine and compare both execution plans, and pick the one that works best for you.  And if both have acceptable performance to you, then I would just pick the one that feels more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
WITH temperature (sID, rTime, temp)
AS (SELECT sensorid, reading_time, value FROM data_table WHERE type=0)
SELECT sensorid, reading_time, temp, value as humidity
FROM data_table JOIN temperature ON sensorid=sID AND reading_time=rTime
WHERE type=1
```

**Explanation:**

- `WITH` create temporary table for temperature with all temperature rows
- Tables `JOIN` by time and sensor
- Selecting temperature from temporary table and humidity from original table for each sensor-time pair

Comment: The only note is that you should check performance of this two methods, I don't fully understand using of agreg. funcs in first answer, but it is possible that they will work faster. However, that is a strange solution and usually DB server optimise WITH statements and it works faster than you think.